# Include variables as strings inside a Visio shape?

Tags: excel, visio

Can I include external data as text strings in Visio, or are they locked to shapes?

I have successfully converted a set of json settings in key-value format to a two-column Excel spreadsheet. I can import the values to Visio, and can produce a shape with only the value in it. I want to insert the value as *part of* the text field in the shape. So, for the value "Save," rather than a process box labeled "Save" (what I can do now), I want a process box with the caption "User presses the Save button." In other words, "User presses the $value button." where $value = Save (keyed to the cell content in that row in Excel.)

Is this possible, am I cooking up a use case that Microsoft does not support, or (ulp) "You can do it, but first you have to learn Visual Basic?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible without VBA. You could consider "Field" (check it out in the documentation). You could use "Insert -> Field", then choose "custom formula". Then the syntax will be something like

`"User presses the " & Prop.Value & " button."`

This assumes that you have property "Value" in your shape.
Check out related [KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/254730/how-to-display-custom-properties-as-text-in-visio)